# How to define an unknown object property key in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

With the Vue composition API we created the following composable:

```js
import { computed, reactive, SetupContext, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export const useApplications = (root: SetupContext['root']) => {
  const applications = reactive({
    1: {
      name: ref(root.$t('app1.name')),
      description: ref(root.$t('app1.description')),
      formName: 'app1form',
    },
    2: {
      name: ref(root.$t('app2.name')),
      description: ref(root.$t('app2.description')),
      formName: 'app2form',
    },
  })

  const getApplication = (id: string) => {
    return applications[id]
  }

  return {
    applications: computed(() => applications),
    getApplication,
  }
}
```

Although the code works fine it generates the TS error:

> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return: Unsafe return of an any typed value

When hovering over the `applications` section it's clear that typescript recognizes the types except for the property name (`1`):
[image]

Do we need to create an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface) to solve this and do we have to redefine each and every property in the interface? I tried something like this but it is incorrect:

```
interface IApplication {
  [key]: string {
    name : string
    description: string
    formName: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why use an object with numeric keys rather than an array?

Comment: For the [limitations](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api#limitations) with arrays in the composition API in Vue 2

Comment: I'm going to have to trust that that's an answer if you know the libraries involved. Otherwise, it doesn't seem to explain anything.

Comment: Using an `array` was what I first did. But there are [issues](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api#limitations) with that approach for the Vue reactivity system in Vue 2. Thanks for the help anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't generally type things so they can be indexed by any string key. As you say, you can define an interface for it:

```typescript
interface IApplications {
    [key: string]: {
        name : string;
        description: string;
        formName: string;
    };
}
// ...
const applications: IApplications = ...
```

Or you might just use a type for the object part of that and use the built-in `Record` type for `applications`:

```typescript
interface IApplication {
    name : string;
    description: string;
    formName: string;
}
// ...
const applications: Record<string, IApplication> = ...
```

Or combining the two:

```typescript
interface IApplication {
    name : string;
    description: string;
    formName: string;
}
type IApplications = Record<string, IApplication>;
```

(Or you can inline the `IApplication` part. Or... :-) )

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. I was just hoping not to have to redefine the properties `name`, `description` and `formName` as they are already known by TS by auto interpretation. But it seems we need to create a complete object.

Comment: @DarkLite1 - Yeah, it'd be nice if it could infer that part. Maybe it's possible (so much is), I'm just not immediately seeing it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the structure of the parameters of `reactive` function, the interface could be defined like :

```
interface IApplication {
  [key:string]:{
        name : string
       description: string
       formName: string
  }
}
```

and

```
const applications = reactive<IApplication>({ ...
```

But I want to suggest another approach which define tha `applications` as `reactive` parameter which has an array as value:

```
import { computed, reactive, SetupContext, ref ,toRef} from '@vue/composition-api'
interface IApplication {
    name : string
    description: string
    formName: string
  }

export const useApplications = (root: SetupContext['root']) => {
  const state= reactive<Array<IApplication>>({ applications :
    [{
      name: ref(root.$t('app1.name')),
      description: ref(root.$t('app1.description')),
      formName: 'app1form',
    },
     {
      name: ref(root.$t('app2.name')),
      description: ref(root.$t('app2.description')),
      formName: 'app2form',
    }],
  })

  const getApplication = (index: number) => {
    return state.applications[index]
  }

  return {
    applications: toRef(state,'applications'),
    getApplication,
  }
}
```